# Best PHP Data Grid

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Can you advice me good php ajax and mysql data grid. It is supposed to have certain functions such as filtering, search and grouping. I need to generate from database (it could be better if it is open source).

Comment: My opinion is that the best software is the stuff you write yourself. Not because of being self-centred, but because if you write it yourself and things go wrong, it's a hell of a lot easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I have short time. So I need something which makes my job more easy.

Comment: Here is the best solution I could find :https://github.com/lazymofo/datagrid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try this then :

http://datatables.net/

Comment: poor choice in case of dealing with lots of rows (for example 3000) better to try the other one (http://flexigrid.info/) because of AJAXing!

Comment: I suggested flexigrid earlier as my another answer of this question but he wanted something else so that's y i suggedted datatables.

Comment: I noticed it before, but what about a cursory reader?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the best ajax data grid, have a look at this grid : http://flexigrid.info/

It is very simple to apply. Works with json and jquery

Comment: The Flexgrid is most like ExtJs. I looking for something like phpGrid.  Can you suggest something else?